How to interpret model fit in posterior predictive checks between two models that both capture the observations in its 1sigma?
I have two models aimed at explaining a single observed measurement $x_{obs}$:
Simple Model with 26 parameters $f_1(\theta)$. 
Complex Model with 31 parameters $f_2(\theta)$.
Both models are assumed to represent the data generation process underlying the observation, implying they define likelihoods. The noise models used for the two are identical. I used Bayesian inference, specifically Simulation-Based Inference (SBI), to obtain the posterior distributions $p(\theta|x_{\rm obs})$ for each model, with multivariate uniform priors $p(\theta)$ in both cases. My goal is to determine which model provides a better fit to the observed measurement.
After performing Bayesian inference, I sampled from the posterior distributions to conduct posterior predictive checks (PPC) for both models. Here's a summary of the results:
Both models' posterior predictive distributions (PPD) capture the observed measurement within their 1-sigma intervals.
However, the Simple Model's PPD has a much narrower spread compared to the Complex Model's PPD.
The Complex Model's PPD also includes some non-physical values in the 2- to 3-sigma region, likely due to its prior.
Next, I performed a Bayes Factor (BF) comparison between the two models, which showed that both hypotheses are equally preferred (i.e., the Bayes Factor does not strongly favor either model).
Additionally, a global coverage plot indicates that both posterior distributions are well-calibrated, meaning there's no evidence of overfitting or underfitting.
My Interpretation Questions:
Scenario A: Does this mean both models are equally consistent with the observations (since their PPD fits the data), but because the Bayes Factor favors neither, the simpler model should be preferred?
Scenario B: Alternatively, does the larger spread of the complex model's PPD (and the inclusion of non-physical values) suggest that the complex model's posterior should be considered less suitable, even if the Bayes Factor shows no strong preference for the simpler model?
Thanks for your feedback in advance!
